# Drop Packets If Falling Behind With Socket.IO in Node JS

Tags: javascript, performance, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I have a real time sensing application, multiple clients, one processing server.

I have an issue whereby I push out data to the clients as fast as possible using Socket.IO and NodeJS. The issue appears to be that the clients incoming data sent from emits on the server start to stack up and the client falls behind (out of sync).

With sufficient throughput the clients keep up fine. Is there any way I can enforce a policy whereby the server/client will drop any emits older than a specified time period?

The data is throw away and the clients should be kept up to date so I am not worried about losing data that is older than say 2 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

Send volatile messages, which can be dropped if they aren't able to be sent. Socket.IO generally keeps track of if a client has received a message, but with volatile messages, this check isn't done and the Socket.IO process can continue, instead of waiting:

```
socket.volatile.emit('event', data);
```

This is what the documentation states:

> This is basically fire and forget functionally, these messages are not
>   buffered internally for when a client is unable to receive messages
>   for example if the client has network issues or if the client uses a
>   polling transport and is in the middle of a request/response cycle.
>
> So if it doesn't matter if your client misses a couple of messages or
>   events you might want to send these as volatile messages.

Comment: I dont believe this is correct. I have tested with volatile but it doesnt appear to make any impact. The data is still queued for the browser to receive. It will only attempt to not resend the data on failed message attempts which isnt the case. I need something like a message lifetime but cant find anything in the documentation so I'm assuming it doesnt exist.

Comment: The only places where messages can be dropped are the client and the server. Even if you were to send a message with a timestamp, the client would still have to receive it in order to drop it. So yes, it is not implemented.

Comment: I'm thinking I will have to go the route where the client periodically sends a message number (incrementing number which is passed with each message I am sending so far) if this number falls too far behind I can skip some emits from the server. Not ideal but I think this could be the only approach whilst still using socket.io.

Answer (score 2):

To help others that may run into this issue I have devised a locking system so that the server only publishes data when the socket is free.

This means the server still publishes as fast as possible, it just wont stack several outgoing data requests. Beware this is only valid if your messages are throw away and you need up to date information. It also means there is a bit of overhead between messages as the client has to inform the server it is ready for more.

However this means my application remains up to date and doesn't fall behind by requests stacking up, which was noticeable before if you ran one browser locally and another across the network.

**Server.js**

```
var socket = ...; // Create socket

// Create my data, in my project this updates very quickly
// roughly 60 times per second
var my_data = ...;

// Initially set receiving to false as the socket
// has no outgoing data
socket.set('receiving', false);

// Listen for received event, this indicates
// that the client has received an update
// and is now ready to receive more
socket.on('received', function() {
    socket.set('receiving', false);
});

// Function will be called repeatedly to send out data
function update() {
    // Check if the socket is receiving any data
    socket.get('receiving', function(receiving) {
        if(!receiving) {
            // Lock the socket from receiving future updates
            // by setting the receiving variable to true
            socket.set('receiving', true, function() {
                // Now emit data
                socket.emit('update', my_data);
            });
        }
    });

    setTimeout(update, 0); // Recursively call update
}
setTimeout(update, 0); // Start update
```

**Client.js**

```
var socket = io.connect();

socket.on('update', function(data) {
    // Store the data for processing

    // Tell the server we have received the data
    socket.emit('received');
});
```

Comment: You have an infinite loop in your update function as it instantly queues up another call to itself.  This may work but it is not optimal.  It's better to put the `.emit('update'` inside of the `.on('received'` callback since you basically want to send the data update when the server receives the received event.